Some Question about encode ‘From’ and ‘To’ in email
I'm trying to sending email by python's smtplib and email.I found a class email.header.Header using to encode the header of email.It can be used like:
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.header import Header

sender = 'sender address'
receiver = 'receiver address'
smtp_server = 'some server'
username = 'sender address'
password = 'server access code'

content = MIMEText('some content.', 'plain', 'utf-8')
message = MIMEMultipart()
message.attach(content)
message['Subject'] = Header('some subject', 'utf-8')

# Wheather these two lines are right?
message['From'] = Header(sender, 'utf-8').encode()
message['To'] = Header(receiver, 'utf-8').encode()

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, 465)
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message.as_string())
server.quit()
print('Success!')

As is shown in RFC2047(https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2047), the From and To in an email should be encoded if there are non-ascii characters contained.I found examples like:
=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Patrik_F=E4ltstr=F6m?= <paf@nada.kth.se>  Patrik Fältström <paf@nada.kth.se>
From the example, we can see that only the nickname of the sender/receiver is encoded.My question is: wheather the real-email-address should be encoded.
For example, if I want to send an email to paf@nada.kth.se, could I set the "From" and "To" like =?utf-8?b?cGFmQG5hZGEua3RoLnNl?=(paf@nada.kth.se without other things)?
I have made some tests to send email using encoded mail-address.Some of the server refuesd sending when I encoded the "From" for wrong type of "From" , but most of the server success to send it if I just encode the "To" without encoding "From".
As tested-servers seems has different behaivers for that，I want to know the standard behaiver for an email-server .
